# Magento. Add to cart not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, magento, magento-1.7

Magento product details page has button "add to cart"  which not working in IE (I tested on different versions)
Button:

```
 <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

Code in product page:

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
productAddToCartForm.submit = function (button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;
        if (url) {
            form.action = url;
        }
        var e = null;
        try {
            this.form.submit();
        } catch (e) {}
        this.form.action = oldUrl;
        if (e) {
            throw e;
        }
        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
            button.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Also called script from /media/js/d9d0df2fe59a334949de96f1603a1a9b.js

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function () {
    replaceDelUrls();
    replaceAddUrls();
    //Event.observe($('j2t-overlay'), 'click', hideJ2tOverlay);
    var cartInt = setInterval(function () {
        if (typeof productAddToCartForm != 'undefined') {
            if ($('j2t-overlay')) {
                Event.observe($('j2t-overlay'), 'click', hideJ2tOverlay);
            }
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function (url) {
                if (this.validator && this.validator.validate()) {
                    sendcart('', 'form');
                    clearInterval(cartInt);
                }
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            clearInterval(cartInt);
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

How I could fix this error?
I use magento 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Known IE8 bug. Try to add 'return false;' to your onclick handler:

```
onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to set "allow COOKIES" in IE. 
So: Set Safety Standards in IE Settings to "Default" or find a way to allow cookies.